# Return ObservableCollection from linq query

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, linq, windows-runtime

I have following linq snippet

**Note** -> This is Metro App, and [ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br209846.aspx) does not work as expected for grouping/sorting.

```
        ObservableCollection<int> ints = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        ints.Add(3);
        ints.Add(4);
        ints.Add(5);
        ints.Add(6);
        ints.Add(3);
        ints.Add(4);
        ints.Add(1);
        ints.Add(2);


        var groupedInts = ints.GroupBy(i=>i).Select(i=>  new {Key=i.Key, Count=i.Count()});
```

I want following

1. To subscribe to groupedInts or ObservableCollection corresponding to it (basically databinding from WPF/Metro UI to groupInts)
2. Any change in ints (original observablecollection) should be reflected by groupedInts (so that UI subscribing to groupInts/related ObservableCollection can show the changes).

In actual scenario, the data structure is slightly complex (6-7 properties), but the problem boils down to above described issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways I can think of.

**1st** : Use Bindable Linq / Continuous Linq

**2nd** : Create a seperate CollectionView for the groupedInts. When the original collection changes, this should change along with it. [Here's a nice and neat tutorial](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/08/woring-with-icollectionviewsource-in.html)

AngelWPFs idea of Notifying the LINQ property as changed is viable, too.

Comment: Grouping with ICollectionView is the way to go, so +1

Comment: ICollectionView is the way to go in WPF. But that is not working in metro apps. That was the reason for this question. Tagging with WPF was to get other alternatives (like BindableLinq/obtics)

Comment: Hm, you should have mentioned in your question that you are working on a metro app - how are we supposed to know?

Answer (score 1):

Handle the `ints.CollectionChanged` event and refresh your `groupedInts` variable with the same LINQ query there...

Comment: this idea makes sense, i am looking for detaching event as groupedInts will be returned from a function, and will not have any further reference (apart from CollectionViewSource.Source)

Answer (score 1):

You need my [ObservableComputations](https://github.com/IgorBuchelnikov/ObservableComputations) library. Using this library you can code like this:

```
ObservableCollection<int> ints = new ObservableCollection<int>();

ints.Add(3);
ints.Add(4);
ints.Add(5);
ints.Add(6);
ints.Add(3);
ints.Add(4);
ints.Add(1);
ints.Add(2);

var groupedInts = ints.Grouping(i=>i).Selecting(ig =>  new {Key=ig.Key, Count=ig.Count});
```

groupedInts  is [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) and reflects all the changes in the ints collection.